# object-c MD5,BASE64 encrypt can not return fixed value

Tags: ios, objective-c, cryptography, base64, md5

I am using these code to get a MD5+Base64 encrypt string, but when I run the code, it sometime can not return a true encryption string, not often.My encryption code like this:

```
    + (NSString *) md5: (NSData *) data
{
    const char* original_str = (const char *)[data bytes];
    unsigned char digist[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH]; //CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH = 16
    CC_MD5(original_str, (uint)strlen(original_str), digist);
    NSData * md5data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:digist length:sizeof(digist)];
    NSString * result = [md5data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: 1) MD5 is a hashing algorithm, not "encryption". 2) Give an example of how you think this isn't working correctly.

Comment: NSString *postJsonStr = @"{\"Avatar\":\"15021850472670\"}";
    NSData *bodyData = [postJsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *newStr = [Test md5:bodyData];
    
    NSLog(@"__newStr %@", newStr); 

The correctly result was It43JzEhd8qLOaJcqy5I2g==, but sometime it will return jvXhJ5fgnULQPwUbGCsppw==

Comment: Hello,I tried to log the “original_str”,it it seems that somtime it would add two space at the end of the result, such like:{"Avatar":"15021850472670"}{"Avatar":"15021850472670"}

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const char *cStr = [@"fd" UTF8String];
unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_MD5(cStr, (int)strlen(cStr), result);
NSMutableString *md5String = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) {
    [md5String appendFormat:@"%02x", result[i]];
}
NSString *encodedString = [NSString stringWithString:md5String];
NSData *nsdata = [encodedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64Encoded = [nsdata base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Comment: OR get encodedString as `[NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
        result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], 
        result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
        result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
        result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
        ]; `

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution. Just change this code

```
CC_MD5(original_str, (uint)strlen(original_str), digist);
```

to

```
CC_MD5(original_str, (CC_LONG)data.length, digist);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Swift

```
import CryptoKit
import CommonCrypto

func md5(data: Data) -> String {
        let digest = Insecure.MD5.hash(data: data)
        return Data(digest).base64EncodedString()
    }
```